# Syncing Redis with MariaDB

Tags: python, database, caching, redis, mariadb

In my spare time, I'm developing an API where successful queries result in a reduction of the user's available query credits. Currently, I'm utilizing Redis 6 for a temporary cache of the balance data (with a 60-second time-to-live) and MariaDB 10.5 for storing the data persistently.

My concern is about the potential for the cached balance in Redis to become unsynchronized with the data in MariaDB. I'm curious if there's a best practice approach for maintaining consistency between these two data storage systems. If aligning them proves to be too complex, I'm considering forgoing the Redis cache for balance information and relying solely on MariaDB.

Comment: Going for additional services seem only advisable if necessary. Do you have any troubles with `UPDATE user SET api_credits = api_credits -1 WHERE user_id=4  and api_credits > 0` and observing updated_rows to see if any credit was there?

Comment: Yuck!  A cache in front of a cache is often inefficient.  Making room for Redis takes away from RAM might be better used by MariaDB.  And added complexity.  And less assurance of consistency.  "Query credits"??  Maybe we should look at ways to combine queries to decrease the count.